# I cannot find the code that inlines Expression variables

Tags: c#, roslyn

The C# compiler transforms this (for example):

```
Expression<Action> e = () =>Console.WriteLine();
```

into:

```
Expression<Action> expression = 
   Expression.Lambda<Action>(
       Expression.Call(null, 
                      (MethodInfo) methodof(Console.WriteLine), 
                       new Expression[0]), 
                       new ParameterExpression[0]);
```

I can't find  any reference to `System.Linq.Expression<T>` in [the source code](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).

My idea is that it might be simple to make C# support multi statement lambdas.
I've only found the place where design time code analysis bails out an error on blocks in lambdas.

Any ideeas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the wrong thing. Remember that compilers don't necessarily target the same runtime version as what they themselves use. If it made sense (it doesn't), it would even have been possible for Roslyn to be written as completely unmanaged C++, yet still produce verifiable .NET executables. Therefore, if Roslyn actually uses the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<T>` type directly, it would only be used internally, it wouldn't be something that gets copied into any output assembly. Instead, what it does is look up the required runtime types by name.

A good thing to search for here, since you've seen it's used, and you can guess it won't give many false positives, is `ParameterExpression`, where there are only results in two files that are part of the C# compiler: `Src/Compilers/CSharp/Source/Lowering/LambdaRewriter/ExpressionLambdaRewriter.cs` and `Src/Compilers/Core/Source/WellKnownTypes.cs`. The former is the one you want.

Comment: ExpressionLambdaRewriter.cs:435 "// Generate Expression.Call(Receiver, Method, [typeArguments,] arguments)"

Comment: http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Lowering/LambdaRewriter/ExpressionLambdaRewriter.cs#435